# AngularJS directive: Updating the isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to create a directive which displays changing data. For simplicity let's say I want to display the current time. This means that once a second the directive needs to refresh itself.

In [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) there is an example for just this case ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zAMd8fupIFQNQDh6xaJB)), but it procedurally updates the directive's content. I wonder if it could be done using data binding as well.

**I imagine** something like this:

```javascript
module.directive('dateTime', function($interval) {
  return {
    scope: { // start with an empty isolated scope
    },

    template: '{{currentTime}}', // display time fetched from isolated scope

    init: function(isolatedScope) {
      $interval(function() {
        isolatedScope.currentTime = new Date(); /* update isolated scope */
      }, 1000);
    },

    destroy: function() { /* stop interval */ }
  };
}
```

Is something like that possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. The `init()` function you use in your code must be named `link`, and the `destroy()` function must be replaced by a listener on the `$destroy` event on the element passed to the link function:

```
module.directive('dateTime', function($interval) {
  return {
    scope: {
    },

    template: '{{currentTime}}',

    link: function(isolatedScope, element) {
      var interval = $interval(function() {
        isolatedScope.currentTime = new Date(); /* update isolated scope */
      }, 1000);

      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        $interval.cancel(interval);
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rjwYZmR4qJ9Jn28d3jXR?p=preview